# Chrome doesn't let me change the number of questions per page

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, pagination

On the Stack Overflow homepage, at the bottom, I can choose between 15, 30 or 50 questions per page. I'm able to change this value when using Safari but when I go back to Chrome, it doesn't let me switch the value. (Chrome 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit) on OS X Yosemite).

Comment: looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. It will be out in the next build.